# Reformat the content and look of SharePoint alerts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is it possible to reformat (content and look) of an alert email sent by Sharepoint 2007? If yes, how do define the format and content?

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways that you can customize SharePoint alerts:

1. By modifying the template file that defines alerts, and
2. By creating a class that implements `IAlertNotifyHandler`.

---

**Modifying Alerttemplates.xml**

You can modify the alert templates that SharePoint uses by copying and modifying the **`Alerttemplates.xml`** found in **`<12 hive folder>\Template\XML`**.

Once you've modified the file, you can update the alert templates in SharePoint by executing the following command:

```
STSADM -o updatealerttemplates -url <site URL> -filename <path to your modified file>
```

For more information see:

- [MSDN: Modifying the Appearance of Alerts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862021.aspx)
- [MSDN: Alerts in Windows SharePoint Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897925.aspx)

---

**Implementing IAlertNotifyHandler**
This gives you more fine-grained control over the contents of emails that are sent for alerts.

You create a class that implements `IAlertNotifyHandler` and override the `OnNotification` method.

For more information see these links:

- [MSDN: Implementing Alert Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897791.aspx)
- [How To: Customizing alert emails using IAlertNotifyHandler](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/14/how-to-customizing-alert-emails-using-ialertnotificationhandler.aspx)

Comment: This would be a machine level change which applies to all alerts from all sites on the box right?

Comment: The changes are applied at the web application level.

Answer (score 0):

Expand on dariom's answer. It is a great answer, big thumb up to you!

I tried modifying the template file solution which is easily, but what I achieved is just change the format of email, not the content, which I intended to just show what changed rather than just tell something changed. I end up use a tool called SharePoint Alert Reminder.

Maybe I missed some things, if so could you elaborate on it further.